# Python use multiple operators in a boolean expression

Tags: python, if-statement, controls, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

### Background

As we all known, we'd better not assginment several variables use `chain assignment` like `a = b = [1,2,3]`, because `a` will be a shalow copy of `b`. It is not safe because `a` will change when we revise `b`.

However, if the initialization is **immutable**, we can do like this `a = b = 1` and it's safe.

Recently, I find a strange usage of multiple operators in the condition expression of a *control flow*, like `if 1 < b < 2:` or `while a == b == c == 1:`

For example, the following control flow excute different chunks under different conditions:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 2

if a == b == c == 1:
    print('All equal!')
else:
    print('At least one variable is not equal to others')
```

> At least one variable is not equal to others

---

### My question

Is this **multiple operation usage** safe in a boolean expression in within a *control flow*? I know we should check the [**operator precedence**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) when we write a **boolean expression**. **Is there anything else we should keep an eye on?** I try for a while and I think the *multiple operator usage* is safe.

---

### Bytecode analysis

I type the *bytecode* of the following program:

```
a = 1;b =2;c =1.5
a<b<c
import dis
dis.dis('a<b<c')
```

> ````
>   1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
>               2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
>               4 DUP_TOP
>               6 ROT_THREE
>               8 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
>              10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
>              12 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
>              14 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
>              16 RETURN_VALUE
> >   18 ROT_TWO
>              20 POP_TOP
>              22 RETURN_VALUE```
> ````

I can only recognize that it compare `a` and `b` at step 10 and then compare `a` and `c` at step 14. But why it still return `False`. I not familiar with analysing *bytecode*. If someone can help with analysing it, I will be very appreciated!  Here is an official guide of [Module: dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Comparison and assignment are two different operations. Comparison doesn't have the same issue as `a = b = [1, 2, 3]` assignment.

Comment: I know how to use `assgnment`. I have no question about that. All I wanna know is whether multiple operation usage is safe in a `boolean expression` in within a control flow?

Comment: @Travis Yes it's safe. You can write `multiple boolean expression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code given by you.

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 2

if a == b == c == 1:
    print('All equal!')
else:
    print('At least one variable is not equal to others')
```

Let's understand what it means.`a==b==c==1` is evaluated to `True` only when all three of them are equal to `1`. Else evaluated to `False`. `a==b==c` is evaluated as `a==b and b==c and c==a`.

To get what you wanted you have to do this.

```
if a==b==c==1:
    print('All are equal')
elif (a==b) or (b==c) or (c==a):
   print('At least one variable is not equal to others')
else:
    print('none of them are equal')
```

Now for analysis the second you provided with bytcode.

```
a = 1;b =2;c =1.5
a<b<c
```

`a<b<c` is evaluated as `a<b and b<c` in your case this is `1<2 and 2<1.5` which is evaluated to `False`. `1<2` is evaluated to `True` and `2<1.5` is evaluated to `False`. `True and`False`is evaluated to`False`.

Byte code:

```
In [2]: a=1;b=2;c=1.5

In [3]: dis.dis('a<b and b<c')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
              6 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    14
              8 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             12 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

`6 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    14` What this line tells us is jump to line 14 if false.
In *logical* `and` **`False and any_bool_value`** always evaluates to `False`.

Now if `6 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    14` is `True` then it continues executing `8` to `14`.

And it's safe to use *Multiple boolean operators in a single expression*.

Answer (score 1):

From `0` to `8` it compares `a < b`, at `10` checks if its `False`, if yes go to `18`, rotate stack, pop top value, that is `False`, because `a<b<c` is `a<b and b<c`, so if first value is `False`, does not need to check the second condition.

But in this case `a < b == True`, so it continues. At this point as the it has passed the first checkpoint (`10`) it knows the first condition must have been `True` so it returns whatever the value is from the `b < c` condition, which is `False`, so you get `False`.

On the contrary, if you check disassembly of 'a

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
              6 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     14
              8 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             12 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

It does the opposite, checks (`6`) if the first condition is `True`, if yes, it does not matter what the next condition evaluates to and returns the value, else, returns whatever the next condition evaluates to.